# High MySQL CPU usage after a DDOS attack

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

My server has just been severely ddossed for the past 5 hours and I've managed to ward them off using Cloudflare's firewall. The only problem is that the CPU usage is still running at high CPU amounts (varies between 300-500%) with 33.2gb of Virtual Memory used (information grabbed using `htop`).

How can I get this back to normal? Is there anything I need to do? I've tried restarting the server, apache, and mysql but it still remains high.

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
ANDl very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a gruelling couple of days, I found out what the issue was.

The DDOS basically caused hundreds of thousands of sessions to be created at `/storage/framework/sessions` (using the file driver), so when the session garbage collector ran, it was checking every single file.

I solved this by changing the expiry of the session to 1 hour (I had it set to 24 hours).

Comment: So, it wasn't a MySQL issue?  Which "framework"?

Comment: Nope, surprisingly. It was Laravel.

Answer (score 2):

maybe just reboot the whole vm..

things you could check before:

- is the memory full and the system already in swap ( `free -m` ) , you could try drop caches `sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3` , and then try to lower swappines or even `swapoff -a` , since once the system is in swap , there is a high disk load , and all your latency goes up
- check if somebody still has access to your site ( e.g. exploits , remote code, sql injection )
- you might still have many open tcp connections , try [Cutter](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/cutting-the-tcpip-network-connection-with-cutter.html)
- if your database tables got heavily fragmented or just too large , you might investigate with `mytop`
- if cutter / reboot / restart does not help , ty to investigate with mysql slow logs if something drains your performance

Comment: The ram usage is only about 33%. I still have 20gb of ram remaining. 
Rebooting, restarting, etc doesn't seem to help. I have checked the slow logs and there is nothing that sticks out either.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely explanation is that the DDoS resulted in some of the tables growing massively bigger as a consequence of the DoS. Check your table sizes for large unexpected growth since your most recent backup.

What probably happened was that you had poorly written queries operating on those tables and doing full table scans or something similarly inefficient. As those tables got big, the performance of those poorly written queries tanked. Install mytop and look at what queries are running and eating all the CPU - the chances are there are only 1 or 2 showing repeatedly. Fix those, or see what tables they are using and prune the data in the tables, and you should be back to normal operation.

I hope this helps and saves you upwork costs. ;-)

Comment: You were so close! It was caused by a massive increase of sessions (I used the file driver so each session left an individual file). Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad I could help. :-)